# FB share - не отрабатывает поделиться изображениями

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Столкнулся с проблемой расшаривания изображений через FB на сайте. Есть самописная дашбоард, юзеры логинятся и им показываются некие изображения, пытаюсь расшарить их через FB.

Например простой скрипт шаринга:

```
<a onclick="Share.facebook('http://www.mysite.com.ua/jquery-dom/','Bla-bla','http://

www.mysite.com.ua/img/jquerylogo256-210x210.jpg','Bla-bla')">Share all</a>
```

JS:

```
Share = {
    facebook: function(purl, ptitle, pimg, text) {
        url  = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100';
        url += '&p[title]='     + encodeURIComponent(ptitle);
        url += '&p[summary]='   + encodeURIComponent(text);
        url += '&p[url]='       + encodeURIComponent(purl);
        url += '&p[images][0]=' + encodeURIComponent(pimg);
        Share.popup(url);
    },

    popup: function(url) {
        window.open(url,'','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
    }
};
```

Но ничего не расшаривается, а точнее предлагает расшарить главную страницу www.mysite.com.ua, при этом в окне шаринга не отображается изображение для шаригна.

Может быть это из-за авторизации в дашбоард, т.к. сайт извне просто не может получить доступ к внутреннему контенту и изображениям?

Как можно побороть это дело?

Как это обойти?

Comment: на сколько я знаю у facebook для любых действий есть какое-то API, посему невижу смысла формировать http запросы самому

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, наоборот, формирование строки позволяет уйти от ненужных подключений js библиотек. Проблема в том, что даже https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ тулза не может получить доступ к контенту сайта, так как контент динамически создается и изображения парсятся из других сайтов. Что можете еще посоветовать?